# Mariadb using all cpu on Ubuntu VPS and makes server unresponsive

Tags: ubuntu, vps, mariadb

I have couple of ecommerce websites on one Ubuntu VPS with 4 CPU cores and 16GB of RAM.

Nothing really intensive it ran perfectly fine even on shared hosting.

However now I am having issue with mariadb. Once mysql service is started it begins poping more and more processes until it takes whole CPU and then web page is taking forever to open.

I haven't touched anything in configuration, I am backend developer and not really into server administration so any advice would be much appreciated.

[image: top usage]

[image]

Comment: How large is your database? Do you log slow queries? How much traffic do you see? What does mariadb logs show in general?

Comment: SHOW PROCESSLIST; and enable slow_log, also, dmesg look for any harddrive related issus. Anything interesting?

Comment: It shows bunch of processes with single query which are stucked in sending data state. I haven't changed that query for some time. It may not be the best in the world, but I am wondering why it started now.

Comment: Can you add more detail based on what you found to your question?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the help. Looks like the traffic in website increased for the past few days, hence made the problem in question. The query had GROUP_CONCAT clause and some COUNT, so not really light weight. I switched that to separate query and water started flowing again. :) Thanks again.

Comment: if its solved please remind that you should add an answer

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
AND very helpful OS information, includes - 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: (Alas, process states, such as "sending data", are usually not helpful.)  We need to see the full query, plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: For now the issue seems to be gone, to some extent at least, with fixed query in question. I will take your suggestions, and inspect it further, and will get back to you with information.

Answer (score 0):

You have 16GB of RAM?  But `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is only `128M`?  Change that to `8G`.  (I can't be sure that it will help for CPU.)

Look in the [*SlowLog*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog) for the 'worst' query; then ask us for help in speeding it up.